# Pass data to BroadcastReceiver from Activity using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass an object to a BroadcastReceiver which will do something when a download is finished. How do I access the Intent object in the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method from my activity? Right now I have this in my activity:

```
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
long id = manager.enqueue(request);
```

and I have this in my BroadcastReceiver that does stuff when the download is complete:

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

It all works fine, my BroadcastReceiver does what I want when the download completes. But now I want to pass an object from my activity to the BroadcastReceiver. Usually, I would just create an Intent and add the object to the Intent. But, I haven't created an Intent in my code because the BroadcastReceiver responds to the download using the Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE.

In my BroadcastReceiver, I want to get data from the Intent object in the onReceive() method here:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    intent.getParcelableExtra("object");
}
```

How do I pass data into this Intent object from my activity? How do I access it? I tried using `getIntent().putExtra("object", object)` but it seems to be a different Intent than the one used in the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method because I get a nullPointerException

**Edit: here is my relevant code in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.android.devon.appfrenzy.DownloadReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before download is executed, save the value in SharedPreference

```
editor.putInt(MainActivity.CERIS_LAST_DW_ID_KATALOG, m_intIdKatalog);
editor.commit();
```

Then in onReceive get the value from Shared Preference

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences mCeris;
    mCeris = arg0.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.CERIS_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int m_intIdKatalog = mCeris.getInt(MainActivity.CERIS_LAST_DW_ID_KATALOG, 0);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> But now I want to pass an object from my activity to the BroadcastReceiver.

That's not possible. The `BroadcastReceiver` does not exist, except when receiving the broadcast. Your entire process is perhaps gone by the time the download is complete.

You are welcome to store something in a persistent location (`SharedPreferences`, database, file) and read that in from `onReceive()`. That's the only way to pass data to an object that does not exist in a process that may not yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this because using local storage doesn't work if you're trying to keep track of multiple queued downloads.  Luckily the brainiancs at Google pass the `Download ID` through as an extra, so you can use:

```
        long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0)
```

Then use

```
            public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
                {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0)

                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(downloadId);

                    Cursor cursor = manager.query(query);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                        int reason = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
                    }

                    cursor.close();

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

while calling send broadcast send data as

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("string_example", "here is a broadcasted string");
    i.putExtra("int_example", 100);
    sendBroadcast(i);
```

and in side onReceive() get data from Intent as

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name), "broadcast string: " + intent.getStringExtra("string_example"));
        Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name), "extra!: " + intent.getIntExtra("int_example",0));


    }
```

Modify as ur need...

Comment: Will calling sendBroadcast(i) call the BroadcastReceiver more than once though? Because right now, my BroadcastReceiver gets called without calling sendBroadcast() and without creating an intent.

Comment: are you using registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)); to register receiver for download manager

Comment: No, It's in my xml though. I am using the code provided in my question as well as the receiver code in my AndroidManifest.xml. Check my edit to see the xml