# Send data to BroadcastReceiver that is broadcasted in DownloadManager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using the DownloadManager to download files and listening to `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` to know when the download is completed. I'm registering a broadcast receiver this way:

```
    <receiver android:name="my.path.DownloadCompleteReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public static class DownloadCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        ....
    }
}
```

How would I send extra data to the DownloadCompleteReceiver so that I can execute some logic there?

Comment: What extra data, specifically?

Comment: @DougStevenson simple String values

Comment: Try using putExtra() -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: To which intent should I use putExtra()? My code doesn't `sendBroacast(..)`, the broadcast is sent from the DownloadManager library

Comment: That's not possible directly, anyways you can save and retrieve later using SharedPreferences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210900/pass-data-to-broadcastreceiver-from-activity-using-downloadmanager

Comment: and here the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309637/set-extras-for-downloadmanagers-broadcastreceiver?noredirect=1

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate, thanks @MKJParekh!